# Aggregate pandas dataframe by n consecutive lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe de type OHLC (open, high, low, close) and I am trying to resample it, not using dates, but simply by aggregating 2 consecutive rows (ideally starting from the bottom of the dataframe, meaning that the last row would always be aggregated with another row, even if the number of rows of the initial dataframe is not even):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Open':[1,2,3,4], 'High':[7,10,8,7], 'Low':[0,1,2,3], 'Close':[4,2,7,4]})


Out[6]: 
   Open  High  Low  Close
0     1     7    0      4
1     2    10    1      2
2     3     8    2      7
3     4     7    3      4
```

The required output is:

```
   Open  High  Low  Close
0     1     10   0      2
1     3     8    2      4
```

I have tried to achieve this column by column, and then aggregate them to form the final dataframe:

```
df2_high = df['High'].groupby(df.index // 2).max()
df2_low = df['Low'].groupby(df.index // 2).min()
```

...but I struggle to see how to determine df2_open and df2_low, which would be respectively the Open value of the 1st row and the Close of the 2nd row?

Hopefully there is an elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with `groupby` + `agg`

```
s = df.groupby(df.index//2).agg({'Open':'first','High':'max','Low':'min','Close':'last'})
   Open  High  Low  Close
0     1    10    0      4
1     3     8    2      7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Yoben, unfortunately Open and Close do not match the requirement it seems. Let me clarify, when aggregating two rows, open should always be the open of the row of the lower index (not a min) and close should always be the close of the row of the higher index. Hopefully this makes more sense. Also, ideally we would start the aggregation at the bottom of the dataframe, so we aggregate the last 2 rows, then the following two rows, etc, until we reach the top (so the row of index 0 could be on its own if the initial dafaframe length is an odd number).

Comment: @BakaB change min to first and max to last

Comment: That seems to work! Brilliant thanks mate! Any idea how to reverse the aggregation, it seems to be top to bottom, I would prefer bottom up? With a dataframe of 5 rows, the solution you proposed results in the bottom row being not aggregated?

Comment: @Baka change `(df.index.max()-df.index)//2`

Comment: Thanks,  I replaced df.index//2 by what your proposed but I get ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Comment: @Baka then df=df.iloc[::-1,:]; df=df.reset_index(drop=True); df.groupby(df.index//2).agg({'Open':'first','High':'max','Low':'last','Close':'max'})